# I want to let users create a new socket in socket.io. Any way can I do this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am working on a web-based Audience Response System.

To do this, I need to add multichannel support in order to simultaneously run the system on different classes. I planned to use a different socket name to send different values, so it's going to be like

- Class A set the class name to "exampleA", and clients in class A transmit data through socket name "exampleA"
- Class B set the class name to "demoB", and clients in class B transmits data through socket name "demoB"
- Socket names aren't specified since the initial start of node.js server, so I need to get the name from a user, and then start a socket with name specified.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: From what I know , there always will be different client sockets for different clients. What remains same is your server side socket. But then I have no idea what you're trying to achieve. Class A and Class B description confused me a little bit.

Comment: Socket.IO can support this kind of segregation via namespaces and rooms: http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/